# Border for the select dropdown on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have an html select element and the corresponding options as shown in the sample HTML below. I want to give border to each and every option in the list, but that is not working on chrome although it works on firefox. Please tell me how it can be accomplished

```
<select id="sortingOptions" class="sortingOptions" onchange="window.location='/buyer/OutPDir.jsp?psort=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">                    
<option value="0">Best Match</option>                                       
<option value="1" selected="selected">Price: Low to High</option>                                       
<option value="12">Price: High to Low</option>                                      
<option value="10">Product Rating</option>                                      
<option value="13">Date Added</option>                                  
<option value="3">Number of Sellers</option>                                        
<option value="14">Best Selling</option>
```

[image: select drop down]

Comment: Tried this? `<select style="border: 1px solid red">`

Comment: that works to give the border to the default selected option, and not all the options as shown in the picture above

Comment: Then hace you tried using something like jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buddy my option for this is jQuery. That will be cross browser and cross platform. I hope IE 7 or 8 don't have any objections!

You can use this:

```
<div>Select:</div>
```

And under this show a list as

```
<ul style="display: none;">
 <li>Option one</li>
 <li>Option two</li>
 <li>Option three</li>
 <li>Option four</li>
</ul>
```

And after this, you can use jQuery as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('div').mouseover(function() { // if mouse hovers the div!
    $('ul').show(); // show the list..
  }
});
```

This way, you can style the list in any way! And every browser will accept the CSS and JavaScript!